# how to add scrollBar in TextInput?

Tags: react-native

Someone know how to add scrollBar in TextInput?
I tried use , but it doesn't help.
multiline={true} doesn't help too

```
  <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              placeholder={selectedCategory ? 'Add' : 'New'}
              multiline={true}
              placeholderTextColor="#979aaa"
              value={description}
              onChangeText={(text) => setDescription(text)}
            />

input: {
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    color: 'black',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 8,
    marginBottom: 10,
    height: 200,
    textAlignVertical: 'top',
  }
```

Comment: TextInput by default comes with scrollview inside it, when we apply multiline={true}, Try adding multiple enters in input for new line to better testing